# What should be the format of one-hot-encoded features for scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use the regressor/classifiers of scikit-learn library. I am a bit confused about the format of the one-hot-encoded features since I can send dataframe or numpy arrays to the model. Say I have categorical features named 'a', 'b' and 'c'. Should I give them in separate columns (with `pandas.get_dummies()`), like below:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

or like this (merged all)

| merged |
| --- |
| 1,1,1 |
| 1,0,1 |
| 0,0,1 |

And how to tell to the scikit-learn model that these are one-hot-encoded categorical features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a feature containing a merged list directly to the model. You should one-hot encode into separate columns first:

- If you just want something quick and easy, [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) is fine for development, but the following approaches are generally preferred by most sources I've read.
- If you want to encode your input data, use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (OHE) to encode one or more columns, then merge with your other features. OHE gives good control over output format, stores intermediate data and has error handling. Good for production.
- If you need to encode a single column, typically but not limited to labels, use [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) to one-hot encode a column with a single value, or use [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) to one-hot encode a column with multiple values.

Once you have your one-hot encoded data/labels, you don't need to "tell" the model that certain features are one-hot. You just train the model on the data set using `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)` and make predictions using `clf.predict(X_test)`.

**OHE example**

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd

X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X_enc = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Convert to dataframe if you need to merge this with other features:
df = pd.DataFrame(X_enc, columns=ohe.get_feature_names())
```

**MLB example**

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'style': ['Folk', 'Rock', 'Classical'],
   'instruments': [['guitar', 'vocals'], ['guitar', 'bass', 'drums', 'vocals'], ['piano']]
})

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoded = mlb.fit_transform(df['instruments'])
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded, columns=mlb.classes_, index=df['instruments'].index)

# Drop old column and merge new encoded columns
df = df.drop('instruments', axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, encoded_df], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: What about MultiLabelBinarizer() ?

Comment: @MehmedB MLB is used to encode the labels. I added MLB into my answer for more clarity. Let me know if you still have questions. If you want to get more specific, please add a code sample to your question.

Comment: So, finally, does that mean I can send a DataFrame in which the categorical features (one-hot-encoded) are in separate columns or not (for sklearn models)? or do I have to send one-hot-encoded array (each row merged into an array instead of seperate columns)

Comment: They need to be one-hot encoded in separate columns and merged with any other features you have (for input matrix `X`). If you're one-hot encoding the labels (`y`), then you pass the labels encoded in separate columns in the `fit(X, y)` method (no need to merge to your feature matrix since labels are passed in a separately argument).